# how to make vlookup range with variables?

Tags: excel, vba

```
line 1: ActiveCell = "=vlookup(a2:a18,sheet1!a2:l150,match(b1,sheet1!a2:l2,0),0)"


line 2: ActiveCell=  "=vlookup("a2:a"&i,sheet1!a2:l150,match(b1,sheet1!a2:l2,0),0)"
```

Value `i` is a variable, say `i= 7`.

I want syntax in line 2 to work but getting some syntax error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
ActiveCell = "=vlookup(A2:A" & i & ",sheet1!a2:l150,match(b1,sheet1!a2:l2,0),0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveCell = "=vlookup(a2:a" & i & ",sheet1!a2:l150,match(b1,sheet1!a2:l2,0),0)"
```

Is there a reason you are looking up a range? Never done that myself, should you be using the below?

```
ActiveCell = "=vlookup(a" & i & ",sheet1!a2:l150,match(b1,sheet1!a2:l2,0),0,0)"
```

Comment: FYI:  0 or false are same thing here.

Comment: My bad, I knew 0 was the same thing but I'm so used to using FALSE I didn't spot it was there. Edited answer.